# Hawking radiation and Einstein-Cartan theory

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Einstein-Cartan theory is an alternative to GR which allows for spin to affect torsion.

The result is that a black hole doesn't collapse to a point and instead bounces back into a white hole and has non-infinite density.

I was wondering if anyone has rederived Hawking radiation in the context of Einstein-Cartan theory and therefore solved the trans-Planckian problem for Hawking radiation, as rewinding time doesn't mean that you are dealing with lengths smaller than the Planck length.

Edit: for that matter, why is general relativity studied more than Einstein-cartan theory? The only difference between the two is this assumption made by general relativity that torsion does not affect spacetime. This is exactly that, an *assumption*. Einstein-Cartan theory has *equal* evidence for it, as it predicts everything that GR predicts, however they disagree e.g. on what happens in black holes. Surely Einstein-Cartan theory should be regarded as a better theory as it doesn't make an assumption, and avoids singularities which most people would say is due to the incompleteness of GR.

I may be so bold to assume Einstein made this assumption because I have read that the geometry of general relativity cannot take into account continuity/conservation of torsion. This is what led certain to develop Cartan geometry, which is just a better version of Riemann geometry as it possesses Lorentz symmetry.

Comment: Torsion applies only in the matter filled regions. In vacuum regions spacetime still is Ricci flat. The Hawking radiation originates from a vacuum region outside the horizon. Nothing inside the horizon can have any effect on anything outside whether or not you have torsion. Why do you think torsion would affect the Hawking radiation? Also, in what solution does a black hole collapse to "a point" of an "infinite density"? A singularity certainly is not a point and doesn't have such a property as density.